# What's wrong with my sql with ORA-00904?

Tags: sql, oracle

What's wrong with my sql?I work's well in sybase but work wrong in oracle.

```
    select Col1 as bus_type,
           count(*) as cnt,
           sum(count(*)) as sums  
      from t_form_25
     where Node_value ='6' 
  group by bus_type
  order by cnt desc
```

And it shows:

> [Err] ORA-00904: "BUS_TYPE": invalid identifier

How to fix it? It works well in sybase.

Comment: You can't access a column alias in the `where` or `group by` clause.

Comment: also, aggregate of an aggregate `sum(count(*))` can't be done in the same query.

Comment: group by col1 instead of bus_type. sum with nested count is not permitted

Comment: @vkp: actually you can in some situations, e.g. when no other columns are selected: `select max(count(*)) from foo group by bar` is valid in Oracle.

Comment: yes @a_horse_with_no_name..i was telling about this specific query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two errors in your code!

- You cannot refer to an alias on the `GROUP BY` clause on the same level he was created.
- You can't do an aggregation function on aggregation function on the same level! again, you have to wrap it with another select if you want to use it.

So:

```
SELECT bus_type,cnt,sum(cnt) OVER(ORDER BY 1) sum_cnt
FROM (
    select Col1 as bus_type,
           count(*) as cnt  
      from t_form_25
     where Node_value ='6' 
  group by Col1)
GROUP BY bus_type,cnt
order by cnt desc
```

I don't entirely understand what did you try to do here, maybe you will have to omit one of the columns because right now the sum will always be equals to the `cnt`.

Comment: [Err] ORA-00937: not a single-group group function

Comment: Sorry typo, forgot to delete the sum(count(*)) as @a_horse_with_no_name pointed out.

Comment: What is the meaning of this sum(cnt). You group by bus_type,cnt and it will be equal to cnt. Do you want sum of all cnts than sum(cnt) over () or when by bus_type, sum(cnt) over (partition by bus_type)

Comment: @Mottor That's what I said on the last sentence of my answer.

Comment: OK. Sorry. Actually sum(cnt) will be = cnt, not 1

Comment: Yea, my bad, that's what I meant. @Mottor

Comment: @sagi,@Mottor,Actually,I want the total sum! But sum(cnt) will be = cnt,How to change it ?

Comment: Sorry,It is OK now.Because the network speed is very slow.I click it many times.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot group by the alias you have..Just try this..

```
    select Col1 as bus_type,
           count(*) as cnt,
           sum(count(*)) as sums  
      from t_form_25
     where Node_value ='6' 
  group by Col1
  order by cnt desc
```

Comment: [Err] ORA-00937: not a single-group group function

Answer (score 0):

```
select Col1 as bus_type,
count(*) as cnt,
 from  t_form_25
where Node_value ='6' 
group by Col1
order by cnt desc;
```